# Run a shell script and immediately background it, however keep the ability to inspect its output

Tags: bash, background-process, daemon, gnu-screen, job-control

How can I run a shell script and immediately *background* it, however keep the ability to inspect its output any time by tailing `/tmp/output.txt`.

It would be nice if I can *foreground* the process too later.

---

#### P.S.

It would be really cool if you can also show me how to "send" the backgrounded process in to a GNU screen that may or may not have been initialized.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

## To 'background' a process when you start it

Simply add an ampersand (`&`) after the command.

If the program writes to standard out, it will still write to your console / terminal.

---

## To foreground the process

Simply use the [`fg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fg.1p.html) command. You can see a list of jobs in the background with [`jobs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/jobs.1p.html).

For example:

> [`sh -c 'sleep 3 && echo I just woke up' & jobs`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%20sh%20-c%20%27sleep%203%20%26%26%20echo%20I%20just%20woke%20up%27%20%26%20jobs)

---

## To background a currently running process

If you have already started the process in the *foreground*, but you want to move it to the *background*, you can do the following:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to put the current process to sleep and return to your shell. This process will be paused until you send it another signal.
2. Run the [`bg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bg.1p.html) command to resume the process, but have it run in the *background* instead of the *foreground*.

Comment: wow i've been looking for this for years (what you said about "Run the `bg` command ..." )

Comment: Good answer. As an aside: you can more simply send _multiple_ shell commands to the background with a subshell (`(sleep 3 && 'echo I just woke up') &`) or group command (`{ sleep 3 && echo 'I just woke up'; } &`).
To make a redirection part of the background command, place it _before_ the `&`; e.g., `(sleep 3 && echo 'I just woke up') >/tmp/output.txt &`

Comment: Good tips, @mklement0. I should have thought to use `;` in my example since I do not care about the success/failure state of `sleep`.

Comment: Something that was not mentioned: if you don't want the output of the background command to go to your terminal (not redirected) do `stty tostop` and the process will receive a `SIGTTOU` signal, the you can `fg` and see the output.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I tested your method and found that if we use `stty tostop` followed by `bg`, if the background process output to the terminal, it will be suspended immediately again. So this is not a solution...

Comment: @jdhao if the process is doing a long calculation until it produces output it will be a solution

Comment: Recently i've noticed that ctrl Z actually stops the process. As in the process exits. So be careful with this.

Comment: @Owl In my experience sending a stopped job to background does not resume the processes. But if I run `fg` the job, it starts to run again.

Comment: @jarno, that's been my experience too, until recently...

Comment: @Owl Until you started using a specific version of Bash? Or a specific program you stopped?

Answer (score 31):

Another way is using the `nohup` command with `&` at the end of the line.

Something like this

```
nohup whatevercommandyouwant whateverparameters &
```

This will run it in the background and send its output to a nohup.log file.

Comment: Explanation about `nohup`: it's work is to cut the stdin, stdout and stderr. Some execution environments force those closed when the starting environment is closed (e.g. terminal window on X server, login session in true terminal). You get exactly the same results if you redirect stdin, stdout and stderr by yourself.

Comment: Also note that if your system has `systemd` and it has been configured to kill processes started by your user interface once you log out, there's no hack that can make any process survice your logout if the process is direct or indirect child of your user session. Double forking, `nohup` or any other trick cannot escape the `cgroup` containment used by `systemd`. A root process can change cgroups, though.

Comment: How do I do if I want to "`nohup cmd params &`" *with other commands*, like `echo "test" && nohup cmd params & && zip blabla`

Answer (score 7):

One easy to use approach that allows managing multiple processes and has a nice terminal UI is [hapless](https://github.com/bmwant/hapless) utility.

Install with `pip install hapless` (or `python3 -m pip install hapless`) and just run

```bash
$ hap run my-command  # e.g. hap run python my_long_running_script.py
$ hap status  # check all the launched processes
$ hap logs 4  # output logs for you 4th background process
$ hap logs -f 2  # continuously stream logs for the 2nd process
```

See [docs](https://github.com/bmwant/hapless/blob/main/USAGE.md) for more info.

[image: ui]

Answer (score 2):

I tried `nohup` but my process was getting stopped after a day or two , so i tried this simple bash script to rerun my command after it stops

run.sh

```
while true; do
[ -e stopme ] && break
python3 main.py # your command here
done
```

then do

```
nohup bash run.sh &
```