# Send /var/log (syslog) from ECS Fargate container to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have some Fargate container running a backend application, I'm using awslog driver so I can get STDOUT and STDERR in CloudWatch, that works perfectly, but now the application is failing with some funny error "ENOSPC: no space left on device, write" (which is related to npm), and as some folder is full I can't keep working.

In CloudWatch I have not syslogs "/var/log" from the containers to analyze and understand the root of the issue, so Neither do I know what is being written (like temp files or a massive log) nor where, in order to maybe set some crontab to clean up or perhaps to solve it at the code level after checking the syslog.

I wonder if anyone has been able to send /var/log (syslog) from the container to CloudWatch and how it was accomplished?, thanks.

Comment: You can use something like this in your entrypoint script to export syslog to container stdout.

`tail -F /var/log/path/to/logfile &`
`start your application command &`
`wait $!`

Here's related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44222911/4479254

Also, Fargate allows only 10 GB or 20 GB storage. It depends on platform version https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html

Code with formatting https://pastebin.com/VAv7RMTc

Comment: @vallgorr Thanks for your input, I will check this and let you know the results, cheers :-)