# Jest + SuperTest tests passes locally but has error "connect ECONNREFUSED" in GitHub actions CI

Tags: jestjs, continuous-integration, github-actions, supertest

Jest + SuperTest tests pass locally, but GitHub action CI has `connect ECONNREFUSED` error. This seems to be an error caused by not connecting to the server.

When testing locally, I always tested after connecting to the server through `npm run start:dev`. So, I want to be able to run the server in the CI stage to conduct tests, and then shut down the server.

However, when I type the command `npm run start:dev && npm run test`, CI doesn't finish for tens of minutes after the server starts.

How can I make my tests run as successfully in the CI stage as I did locally? I need help. The execution environment is node js.

The code to create a `request` variable and get the API call result is as follows.

`const request = supertest("http://127.0.0.1:55503");`

`const response = await request.get("/test/a");`

Comment: Run server in background, wait for it to start, and then run tests e.g. `npm run start:dev & && sleep 2s`.

Comment: @Azeem What does the & after `npm run start:dev` mean?

Comment: To run it in the background. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222883/run-a-shell-script-and-immediately-background-it-however-keep-the-ability-to-in. You can find multiple threads on this on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a shell script and immediately background it, however keep the ability to inspect its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222883/run-a-shell-script-and-immediately-background-it-however-keep-the-ability-to-in)

Comment: @Azeem

yes this is the answer i want. thank you. I did a test in the ci step via npm run start:dev & => sleep 2s => npm test.

But I have one more question. I need to turn off the server after npm test. What command should I use at this time? Locally, you can use ctrl+c to turn it off, but I don't know what command to enter on ci.

Comment: You need to kill its process. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/how-to-terminate-a-background-process

Comment: @Azeem 

thank you very much. I have one last question, can I ask you?
What happens when I don't shut down the server running in the background for testing in a CI situation? I wonder if github actions will turn it off automatically at some point, or if it will be forced to close when ci is finished.

Comment: Each GHA workflow job runs in a different runner. As soon as a job is complete, its runner goes down i.e. your server will no longer be running.

Comment: @Azeem

To be honest, I'm asking because I made the mistake of not running the command to turn off the server after testing.

I'm glad the server shuts down automatically.

Thanks for your kind comments!

Comment: @Azeem

I faced another problem. Can you provide additional help? I've created a new question on this link below. It seems that there is a problem in the process of connecting the database.  => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499472/jest-supertest-tests-has-error-connect-econnrefused-in-github-actions-ci

Answer (score 0):

- I had a very similar issue recently and I found out I was making a call to a 3rd party api in my test, to solve the issue I had to mock the api call using jest's mock functionalities. If you are not familiar with mocking third party api calls check out [Link to jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).